# what are methods for comparing documents

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

recently I started to a do some research in standardising products data.

Supermarkets often sell the same products at different prices, and it is useful to compare these prices.  To do this, we need to know we are matching the same products from each supermarket.  The problem is, supermarkets will often have small differences in how they name their products and list them on their websites.  We need a tool that can standardise product names, recognising two differently-named products as the same product, while successfully recognising different but similarly-named products as well as differences in quantity. For example, I want to buy rasher, and when you go to search the rasher , we are going to code all rashers even though differently-named and map to HS-codes , I want to know what technologies behind this process?

Additionally, we need these products prices converted to standard units and the products to be aligned with groups defined by the World trade HS-codes. lets say  price of rasher is 2.99 euro per 180g, but now I want to change it to 16.62 euro per kg with some technologies,  An examination of the appropriate Natural language techniques to determine which method best fulfils these goals.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of difference in titles, but for now I will explain two different types :

1- If name of product is separated from pre and post words, then you can "index" product titles with tools like "Apache lucene" and just search for product name and you will get all products with that title.

2- If name of product has came with postfixes and prefixes then you can use "Edit distance algorithms" to find similar products.

For second part of you question, you should define all patterns to catch differences in weight, value, etc. and then unify them.

Comment: for product name matching part, I have done research and asked some people, some materials show that string simairltiy measurement and pattern matching ( Knuth-Morris-Pratt string matching algorithms, Brute Force, Rabin-Karp. )and Fuzzy String Matching approach  are working on string matching, I read those algorithms, but i don't think those are useful for resolve my problems. some people recommend Bayesian filtering techniques, unsupervised learning. To be honest, I check Bayesian filtering out and it usually is used for email. for unsupervised learning methods, still confused.....

Comment: Most of time we just describe how to resolve the problems and dont have one rules or method named

Comment: Can you give me some product name examples, then I will tell you which method is better.

Comment: for example, i want to buy coca cola, but cocola has many variations like pepsi, diet coke, coke zero, coca cola etc, in this case, which method would be best to resolve  issue of coca cola clustering, because string matching method does not work here.

Comment: Second example, if i go to search "orange juice", but the result could also display " juice orange", in fact we don't want juice orange, how can resolve the problem here

Comment: for second example, I think I need to standardise product name, but i don't know how to do this. For first example , I think Clustering analysis is good choice...

Comment: in term of example, I want to say "orange juice" and "juice orange" are different product but similar name...

Comment: First of all coca cola, Pepsi, diet coke, etc. are all sodas not coca colas. So they are different but in a same category named soft drinks. 
As I understood you want to solve this problem with clustering, and I can tell you if you only have titles such as Pepsi and Coca cola and no other information that is not possible at all. 
For the second example (Orange juice and Juice orange) what feature do you want to use for clustering? If you use unigrams or TF-IDF they will be in the exact same cluster. If you use bigrams they don't. I also can tell you clustering is not a solution here as well.